# tableview not filling up entire screen in storyboard with a navigation bar

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

Hi I am new to iOS app development, xcode and swift. Im not sure if this is a problem or what is causing this but when designing my tableview in storyboards and adding constraints all the way round (0,0,0,0) and then segue from my navigation bar to my view controller. My Top constraint drops right under the navigation bar. Initially it does not do this but happens randomly. (Don't want any navigation issues or views being hidden down the line) Link to storyboard problem. I do not know whats causing this please help. can't upload photos provided a link. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select viewcontroller in storyboard and uncheck **Adjust scroll view insects** box in property inspector.